# XSD validation Error: s4s-elt-must-match error

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

Please help to resolve the below error for the XSD as i'm a newbie to xsd

Sample SOAP response XML

```
 <ACCOUNTDETAILS>
 <STATUS></STATUS>
 <RESPONSE></RESPONSE>
 <ACCOUNTID>
 <DETAILS>
 <NAME></NAME>
 <CATEGORY></CATEGORY>
 <LASTMODIFIED></LASTMODIFIED>
  </DETAILS>
  </ACCOUNTID>
  </ACCOUNTDETAILS>
```

XSD generated

```
<xsd:element name="AccountDetailsResponse">
  <xsd:element name="ACCOUNTDETAILS" type="account:Account">
     <xsd:complexType>
       <xsd:sequence>
         <xsd:element type="xsd:string" name="STATUS"/>
         <xsd:element type="xsd:string" name="RESPONSE"/>
         <xsd:element name="ACCOUNTID">
           <xsd:complexType>
             <xsd:sequence>
               <xsd:element name="DETAILS">
                 <xsd:complexType>
                   <xsd:sequence>
                     <xsd:element type="xsd:string" name="NAME"/>
                     <xsd:element type="xsd:string" name="CATEGORY"/>
                     <xsd:element type="xsd:string" name="LASTMODIFIED"/>
                   </xsd:sequence>
                 </xsd:complexType>
               </xsd:element>
             </xsd:sequence>
           </xsd:complexType>
         </xsd:element>
        </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
  </xsd:element>
```

**XSD ERROR:**

**s4s-elt-must-match.1: The content of 'AccountDetailsResponse' must match (annotation?, (simpleType | 
 complexType)?, (unique | key | keyref)*)). A problem was found starting at: element.**

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can not nest `<xsd:element>` within `<xsd:element>` like you do with  *AccountDetailsResponse* and *ACCOUNTDETAILS*. What would like to do exactely? Define an element type? Use a reference toward another element definition?

Comment: Can you please provide with a sample ? Thanks

Comment: Before providing a sample, you should explain what you would like to do exactely, what are your difficulties, and so on. If you require a tutorial, I'm not certain SO is the right place.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you did not provided us with the entire input.  From your schema, I would expect an element `AccountDetailsResponse` around the excerpt you posted.

As you figured out for the other elements, you cannot have an `xs:element` as a direct child of another `xs:element`.  Most likely, using the same as you did for the other elements (an ordered sequence of children) would do what you want:

```
<xsd:element name="AccountDetailsResponse">
   <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
         <xsd:element name="ACCOUNTDETAILS" type="account:Account">
         ...
```

This will not work either, as you cannot have both a `type` attribute, and an embedded `xs:complexType` at the same time.  So probably you will want to get rid of that one `type` attribute.  So the following should work:

```
<xsd:element name="AccountDetailsResponse">
   <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
         <xsd:element name="ACCOUNTDETAILS">
         ...
```